How can I get the count of transactions total for the day and the total from the last 7 days?
I'm struggling with a problem in BQ sql.
giving an example for one of our employees. today is supposed to be the number of transactions they processed on that day and week_ago is the previous total transactions they processed in the last 7 days as a sort of running balance
date 2024-05-28  id9998 today 12    week ago 59

date 2024-05-27  id9998 today 5 week ago 47

I tried solutions from similar questions but I'm not getting the write total sum for the 7 days. Based on the Query I wrote.
WITH previous_data AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      event_date,
      service_provider_id,
      SUM(completed_trips) AS completed_trips
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(event_timestamp) AS event_date,
        driver_id AS service_provider_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) AS completed_trips
      FROM
        `your_project.your_dataset.your_table`
      WHERE 
        final_status = 'complete' 
        AND is_unique = 1
      GROUP BY 
       event_timestamp, transaction_id, service_provider_id
      ORDER BY 
        event_date DESC
    )
    GROUP BY 
      event_date, service_provider_id
  )
)

SELECT
  t1.event_date,
  t1.service_provider_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(t1.event_date) = DATE(t2.event_date) THEN t1.completed_trips ELSE NULL END) AS today_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(t1.event_date) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(t2.event_date), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND DATE(t1.event_date) < DATE(t2.event_date) THEN t1.completed_trips ELSE NULL END) AS week_ago_count
FROM 
  previous_data t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  previous_data t2 
ON 
  t1.service_provider_id = t2.service_provider_id
WHERE 
  t1.event_date <= '2024-05-28' 
  AND t1.event_date > DATE_ADD('2024-05-28', INTERVAL -30 DAY) 
  AND t1.service_provider_id = 'id9998'
GROUP BY 
  t1.event_date, t1.service_provider_id

I tried validating its accuracy by taking a sample for one of our service providers...
I get this result
date| 2024-05-28 |   id9998 | today 12 |    week ago 60

date | 2024-05-27 |  id9998 | today 5 | week ago 30

but I should be getting this result
date| 2024-05-28    | id9998 |  today 12 |  week ago 59

date | 2024-05-27   | id9998    | today 5 | week ago 47

week ago results should be a sum of the last 7 days (but if they only work the last 5 days within that 7-day range then I should get the total of the 5 days)
event_timestamp id  today

2024-05-28  id9998  12

2024-05-27  id9999  5

2024-05-26  id9999  19

2024-05-25  id9999  3

2024-05-24  id9999  13

2024-05-23  id9999  7

2024-05-18  id9999  4

2024-05-17  id9999  4

2024-05-16  id9999  2

2024-05-15  id9999  9

2024-05-12  id9999  9

2024-05-10  id9999  8

Could anybody check how I could fix this?
